# Is there a way to relevel a variable in gtsummary after generating the beautiful table?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am trying to relevel the levels of specific variables in gtsummary object after creating a table. By default the referenced level comes on top(as expected) but sometimes you would want certain order. For this table I would like that the agecat "61-83" be pushed down. I tried it with modify_table but I get
Error in relevel(agecat, ref = "0-20") : object 'agecat' not found

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)

data(trial)

trial <- trial %>%
  mutate(agecat = case_when(between(age, 0, 20) ~ "0-20",
                            between(age, 21, 40) ~ "21-40",
                            between(age, 41, 60) ~ "41-60",
                            between(age, 61, 83) ~ "61-83"),
         agecat = as.factor(agecat),
         agecat = relevel(agecat, ref = "61-83"))

glm(response ~ trt + grade + agecat,
    data = trial, family = binomial) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this:

1. The print of a gtsummary table is essentially a data frame with formatting options to make it pretty. You can sort the underlying data frame using `modify_table_body()` with the `arrange()` function.

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)
packageVersion("gtsummary")


trial2 <-
  trial %>%
  mutate(
    agecat = case_when(
      between(age, 0, 20) ~ "0-20",
      between(age, 21, 40) ~ "21-40",
      between(age, 41, 60) ~ "41-60",
      between(age, 61, 83) ~ "61-83"
    ) %>%
      factor(),
  )

glm(response ~ trt + grade + agecat,
    data = trial2 %>% mutate(agecat = relevel(agecat, ref = "61-83")), 
    family = binomial) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
  modify_table_body(
    ~ .x %>%
      arrange(variable, desc(row_type == "label"), label == "61-83")
  )
```

2. The second approach is to use `contrasts()` to specify which group should be reference. `tbl_regression()` preserves the ordering.

```r
contrasts(trial2$agecat) <-
  contr.treatment(levels(trial2$agecat),
                  base = which(levels(trial2$agecat) == "61-83")
  )

glm(response ~ trt + grade + agecat,
    data = trial2, 
    family = binomial) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE)
```

[image]