# tbl_regression (gtsummary) ordering covariables levels and processing time

Tags: gtsummary

Originally in my df, I had my BMI in numeric format(1-5), which I recoded (underweigh to obese), factored and choose a specific reference using relevel (Normal, originally 3). Then did a logistic regression: y~ BMI+other covariates. My questions are the following :

1- When I plug my logistic in tbl_regression, the levels have undesired orders (underweight, obese1, obese 2, overweight) . Is there a way to rearrange the levels the way I want to (underweight, overweight, obese 1, obese 2)?

2- I used tbl_regression on a small data set which went ok. My new model, however, is based on 3M observation and 13 variables (the database is 1Gb). This time my tbl_regression is taking about 1h to process and out put the table, which is not normal since I have a fast laptop. Is there a way to make this more efficient ? I tried keeping the model only while using tbl_regression and removed the database, but it is still hellishly long. I tried with the trial data and it was ok..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - I recommend using `contrasts()` to set the reference level. The `relevel()` function just moves a factor level to the first position. Examples here [Is there a way to relevel a variable in gtsummary after generating the beautiful table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67328907)

2 - I suspect with such a large model, the confidence interval calculation is what is slowing you down. If you see a big difference in the computation times of `summary()` and `broom::tidy()` *with* the CI calculation compared to `tbl_regression()`, please create an illustrative example (that anyone can run locally) and it can be looked into further.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel ! great package btw. I tried broom::tidy(model, exponentiate=T, conf.int=T) about an hour ago, so it takes about the same time as tbl_regression. I think -like you said- it is tied to the fact that the model is large. Is there a way to overcome this ? or it is what it is ? I could try SAS, but I am not as comfortable with it as R.

Comment: You can try various calculations for the CI or remove it entirely? I don't work in big data....